# Python3.6 on Windows MINGW64 console doesn't run the interpreter

Tags: python, windows, git, bash, mingw-w64

I'm experiencing the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869192/git-bash-wont-run-my-python-files) with Python 3.6. It works well under the Windows console, but it fails to launch or work under MINGW64. Even when I use the direct path of `/c/Python36/python.exe`, nothing happens. I don't get the interactive REPL with the usual Python interpreter version and `>>>` prompt, as I do in the Windows console.

Any pointers on how to debug this?

Answer (score 4):

Ah - further search yielded this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498580/cant-run-python-in-git-terminal) that contained the answer - use `python -i`