# Getting an `stdin is not a tty` error when using python json.tool in git bash

Tags: windows, python-2.7, git-bash, tty

I am using Git Bash on Windows, trying to pretty print JSON output using the command line. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265439/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-json-file-from-the-command-line) answer, I try the following:

```
$ echo '{"print": "this"}' | python -m json.tool
stdin is not a tty
```

My Python version is 2.7.15 (Anaconda).

When I try the same using the native Windows cmd, it works correctly (but I want to use Bash).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would `echo '{"print": "this"}' | python.exe -m json.tool` works better in a git bash session (adding `.exe` to python).

That seems to be a [winpty issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48200434/6309), as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510451/6309).

Comment: Thanks, adding the `.exe` suffix seems to work. The reason is still mysterious to me. I added an alias to avoid typing it everytime: `alias python='winpty python.exe`

Comment: @G.Alon Good call on the alias, I had to do that too. Don't forget that, if you are using a recent enough Windows 10, you could install and use a (fully Linux) Git/python on WSL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), in which case you won't have any pty issue.